# jQuery .slideDown() for each paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, delay, paragraph

I'm trying to make slideDown set some kind of delay everytime I start a new paragraph. Could anyone help me? I think I've seen the step function, but it didn't work for me. I'm a beginner with html/css/javascript

HTML:

```
<p><font color = "white"> >>></font> Opening new terminal . . . </p>

<p> <font color = "white"> >>></font> Successful . . . </p>

<p> <font color = "white"> >>></font> Executing ./xxx </p>
```

Slidedown

```
$( document.body ).click(function () {
  if ( $( "p:first" ).is( ":hidden" ) ) {
  $( "p" ).slideDown(900);
 } else {
  $( "p" ).hide();
} });
```

Comment: You should use the HTML entities `&gt;` and `&lt;` instead of the `<>` characters when you want to display them.

Comment: And CSS (`color: white`), not `<font>`.

Answer (score 1):

do like this

```
 $(document).click(function () {
    if ($("p:first").is(":hidden")) {
        $("p").slideDown(900);
    } else {
        $("p").hide();
    }
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v9W6c/)

Actually in your context you are hide the all p element when body is clicked .then again you click there is no element in the body .instead of you have to use for document click it will be work